# Class definition from shelve

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.5. Fairly new to python but not new to programming. I have three source files as follows (a much simplified version of what I'm actually doing):

c.py

```
class C:
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x
  def method(self):
    print(self.x)
```

init.py

```
import shelve
from c import C
db = shelve.open("DB")
db['key1'] = C("test")
db.close()
```

test.py

```
import shelve
db = shelve.open("DB")
obj = db['key1']
obj.method() # this works
C.method(obj) # this doesn't -- 'C' not defined
db.close()
```

So I run init.py to set up my shelved database. Then I run test.py. It is happy with executing obj.method(), so it seems to know about class C even though I haven't explicitly imported it (Lutz says something about it being stored in the database). But if I try to do C.method(obj) (not that I'd necesarily need to call it this way, but using C as a class (for example to create new objects) has its usefulness) it says 'C' is not defined. But if I add 'from c import C' to test.py then it works. So in one way it seems to know about C's definition, but then again it doesn't. I am curious to know why this is.

Comment: Who is Lutz? You sure you don't mean `from c import C`? You need to import all names not already defined in the module or builtin.

Comment: Yes, I meant 'from c import C'. Will fix it. I am just curious as to why I don't need to import in one case but do need to import in the other. That seems to go against my intuition.

Comment: _Programming Python_ by Mark Lutz, published by O'Reilly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When shelve serializes an object (I believe by pickling it), it stores the import path to the class for unpickling later.  When it retrieves the object, `pickle` imports the module (`c`) and returns an instance of `C` back to you (that is equivalent to the one that was originally serialized).

So far, this isn't anything new to you based on your observations.  However, when it imports `c`, it doesn't import it into your current namespace.  In fact, it imports it into a [very localized namespace](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/pickle.py#l1373).  So while the `c` module has been imported (you can find it in `sys.modules`), you won't find `c` or `C` in your current namespace because you haven't imported it there.

Put another way, simply importing something doesn't make it accessible to *every* module in your program.  It only makes it accessible to the module (actually scope) where it was imported.  I can import [`os`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/os.py), but just because `os` imports `sys` doesn't mean that I immediately have access to `sys`.  I need to import it too before I can start using it.

```
>>> import os
>>> sys
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
>>> os.sys
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
>>> import sys
>>> sys
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

Comment: That makes some sense. But if C is not in the current namespace, how is it able to do  `obj.method()`? It seems like C.method _is_ in my current namespace. What namespace is C.method actually in then?

Comment: `obj` is an _instance_ of `C` so in some sense, you can think of it as carrying the methods around with it (in reality, it's a bit more complicated than that -- instances actually carry their class around with them and then use that to look up the methods).  i.e. You can retrieve `C` (the class) by doing `type(obj)`.  But `C` still "lives" in the `c` namespace event though instances of `C` carry around a reference to `C` wherever they happen to go..

Answer (score 1):

What you have doesn't work for the reasons stated in [mgilson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37953756/355230).

A work-around for the problem would be to manually import the class from the module and assign the class to the name `C` — something along these lines (tested with Python 3.5.1):

```
import shelve
db = shelve.open("DB")
obj = db['key1']
obj.method() # this works

## Begin added code ##
classname = obj.__class__.__name__
module_name = obj.__module__
module = __import__(module_name, globals(), locals(), [classname], 0)
globals()[classname] = getattr(module, classname)
## Added code end ##

C.method(obj)  # this also works now
db.close()
```

Comment: After studying the doc to understand your code, I gather it could also be done this way:

`exec("from " + obj.__module__ + " import " + obj.__class__.__name__)`

Comment: Thanks. I would upvote you if I could, but don't have enough rep yet. I appreciate your responses.

Comment: I understand — you're welcome. There's a module called [`dill`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill/0.2.5) that's like `pickle`, but more powerful, which might help...although I'm not sure how exactly it might fit in with using `shelve`.

Comment: True about `exec` being unsafe. But use of `__import__` is also discouraged, so not sure either way is "good". You have helped me get a little bit under the hood of the language.